# Extend OpenStack Volume

Tags: centos, openstack

I am trying to extend a Volume in an OpenStack instance abd checked the docs from [openstack](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/dashboard-manage-volumes.html) . But there is no extending documented.  Managing with lvm is not really possible. Do you have an idea how to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by dashboard -> project -> volumes -> extend volume.

You can also do the same with command "cinder extend  "
with proper openstack user credentials.